# How to send a simple command via pyserial

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

Just want to send a simple command via serial connection:

```
import serial

with serial.Serial() as ser:
    ser.baudrate = 115200
    ser.port = 'COM11'
    ser.open()
    ser.write(b'input keyevent 20')
```

open connection on COM11, baudrate 115200 and send command "input keyevent 20"

unable to get this to work.

Comment: Do you need to send some end-of-line characters there? If you were typing this manually, would you have to press RETURN?

Comment: Yep, knew it was something simple. needed /r/n at the end of my command. Thanks @larsks